# What's the meaning of "to his hard drive"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Such is the life of a writer,sending off the most personal thoughts
>   possible ***to his hard drive.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the hard disk drive in your computer, where you store files you've created.  When you save a file, you're typically saving it to your hard drive.

Although we'd usually use a verb like *saving* or *writing*, the author here has chosen *sending*.  This is a more figurative way of expressing the same thing, which is appropriate with such poetic-sounding expressions as "Such is the life of a writer".

Here, the writer is writing "the most personal thoughts imaginable" in a word processor.  The writer then saves these thoughts to disk.  This is a fact of life for a writer, according to the sentence you've quoted.